# Why am I getting a type-mismatch error, here?

Tags: scala, generics, type-mismatch

I am unable to understand why the below code gives type mismatch error -
Here I am using generics and at line 11 it is giving type mismatch error. Shouldn't it interpret T as Int.

```
object FunctionParamGeneric {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit= {
    exec[Int](Fun[Int])
  }

  def exec[T]( f:() => T) : T = {
    println("Inside exec")
    f()
  }

  def Fun[T]() : T = {
    println("Inside Fun with key ")
    123
  }
}
```

However, if I do

```
object FunctionParamGeneric {
   def main (args: Array[String]) : Unit= {
     exec[Int](() => 1)
   }

   def exec[T]( f:() => T) : T = {
     println("Inside exec")
     f()
   }

 }
```

It works fine. Because `f` is inferred to be called with an `Int` in the second snippet, I would expect the same to happen in the in first code snippet, but that's not the case. Why not?

Comment: If you want to return `123` why do you want to declare return type as `T`?

Comment: Please remove those line numbers from your code snippets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First snippet:**

You get error because you have specified generic return type for `Fun` while you are returning `Int`.

Suppose if this expression was allowed, now consider these two statements:

```
Fun[Int]()    // would have returned 123

Fun[String]() // what would be output?
```

The first statement would have returned `123` without any problem but what would be the output in second case?

That's why such expressions are not allowed.

**Second snippet:**

In second snippet it works because when you use `exec[Int](() => 1)`, you are passing a literal function as argument while in first snippet you giving definition of `Fun`.

---

To explain it further, if you look at the definition of `exec`:

```
def exec[T]( f:() => T) : T
```

It takes a `Function0` function (which can return any type) as parameter. So when you call `exec[Int](() => 1)`, you are passing function `() => 1` which returns `Int` (*Note* that this is not a generic function). Hence it works.

While in the first snippet, you were defining a generic function `Fun` with generic return type. But from the body of the function you were returning `Int` value.

Comment: Then how we can call function without anonymous function?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
def Fun[T]() : T = {
  println("Inside Fun with key ")
  123
}
```

You're implicitly returning `123`. Which isn't of type `T`, but of type `Int`. So the compiler generates an error.

If you want `Fun` to always return an `Int` you can do that, by defining it as `Fun(): Int = ...`.

Then you should be able to call

```
exec[Int](Fun)
```